# Priority between thread messages?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++builder

Though I am quoting this in context of Borland C++ application, but the question is both specific for Borland as well as generic in nature.

In a Borland C++ project, I observe that a user interaction with the GUI (say a menu item click) is taking less priority than a task delegated to the main thread using Synchronize(), even though the user interaction is happening a few milliseconds earlier. When the main thread is available, the delegated task is done first and then the action corresponding to the user interaction is performed. A worker thread delegates a task to main thread and waits for the task to complete using Synchronize(). So we can equate Synchronize() to SendMessage().

I believe that the user interaction queues up as a message in the message queue and same should be the case with the delegated task. But how does the task execute first? Is there any priority between messages?

Comment: This is very specific to the Borland implementation.  But it would be common for the message loop to first dispatch any requests from the synchronize queue, then continue emptying the message queue.

Comment: @Hans Thanks for replying. I made a little change to question text - "When the main thread is available". Don't know if that will matter but just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to and including C++Builder 5, `Synchronize()` did indeed make a call to `SendMessage()`. But in C++Builder 6, `Synchronize()` was re-written to not use `SendMessage()` anymore (to support Linux under CLX). Requests are now placed in a FIFO queue, and the VCL periodically calls `CheckSynchronize()` to process the queue. Even though CLX is long dead, `Synchronize()` still uses the same FIFO queue (and it has been enhanced over the years).

Aside from that, in cases where `SendMessage()` is used, it does have higher priority. User interactions are posted messages to the main thread message queue (aka `PostMessage()`). Although `SendMessage()` goes directly to a window's wndproc, it is not called until the receiving window's owning thread performs message processing if sent by a different thread (which used to be the case with `Synchronize()`). Pending `SendMessage()` requests to the main thread message queue have higher priority than pending posted messages to the same queue, as there are other threads/processes being blocked until the pending `SendMessage()` requests are processed.

Comment: Lebeau. Thanks for the reply. I guess the FIFO for Synchronize() would be different from the GUI thread's message queue with the former taking more priority over the latter? Also the GUI thread will do the message processing whenever it is idle. Is that correct?

Comment: Starting with BCB6, the FIFO queue is separate from the message queue, yes. Because `Synchronize()` doesn't use the message queue for synchronizing anymore, it actually has a lower priority now. The main thread calls `CheckSynchronize()` when it is idle and when it receives a `WM_NULL` message. `Synchronize()` posts a `WM_NULL` message to the main message queue to "wake up" the main thread to let it know that `CheckSynchronize()` needs to be called soon. This is very different (but more portable) than the old `SendMessage()` logic.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am a bit confused now. Synchronize() is now dependent on a WM_NULL message posted to message queue and a User interaction is also posted to this message queue. How Synchronize() took a higher priority as seen in the project running Borland version 6?

Comment: As I said, `Synchronize()` in BCB6+ is not dependant on `WM_NULL` by itself.  Pending requests are also processed while the message queue is idle.  So it is entirely possible that the `Synchronize()` queue gets processed before the user interaction messages even arrive in the message queue.